# Call to Lambda.invoke with @aws-sdk/client-lambda returns an empty response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

The below (Angular) component calls a Lambda function using @aws-sdk/lambda-client (v. 3.222.0).
Testing the Lambda in the AWS console using the same payload as input is successful.
Also, when called from the Angular app - cloudWatch logs presents a successful run and its return payload:

```
73ec2dbb-a647-43ea-82c6-a30407001d65    INFO    event received:  {
  body: "MATCH (n %7Bname:'Israel'%7D) RETURN n",
  headers: { SignatureHeader: '******' }
}

73ec2dbb-a647-43ea-82c6-a30407001d65    INFO    requestPayload:  MATCH (n %7Bname:'Israel'%7D) RETURN n

73ec2dbb-a647-43ea-82c6-a30407001d65    INFO    Successfully received result:  
{
    "results": [
        {
            "n": {
                "~id": "1d68ae59-deef-4dd7-b97d-d2771f7dd793",
                "~entityType": "node",
                "~labels": [
                    "Country"
                ],
                "~properties": {
                    "keyID": 972,
                    "language": "Hebrew",
                    "codeText": "IL",
                    "image": "flags/il.png",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "name": "Israel"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the browser console shows that the Angular app received an EMPTY result set:

```
Lambda payload:  {body: "MATCH (n %7Bname:'Israel'%7D) RETURN n", headers: {…}}
Creating LambdaClient:  {body: "MATCH (n %7Bname:'Israel'%7D) RETURN n", headers: {…}}
SENDING LambdaClient. command:  {FunctionName: 'simplify-mvp-neptune-query:dev', InvocationType: 'Event', Payload: Uint8Array(102)}
Returned from LAmbda call. resp:  
Uint8Array [buffer: ArrayBuffer(0), byteLength: 0, byteOffset: 0, length: 0, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Uint8Array']
```

As you can see in the last console line, the received buffer is empty, although cloudWatch is sending out a populated object.

This is the client (Angular) side calling:

```
import { Lambda } from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda";

...

async queryLambda(data: any) {
    console.log('Creating LambdaClient: ', data);
    const lambdaClient = new Lambda({ 
      region: environment.awsRegion,
      credentials: {        
        accessKeyId: environment.awsAccessKeyLambda,
        secretAccessKey: environment.awsSecretLambda,
      }
    });

    console.log('Creating InvokeCommand');
    const command = {
      FunctionName: environment.awsLambdaDBFunction,
      InvocationType: 'Event',
      //Payload: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)),
      Payload: new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(data))
    };
  
    
    try {
      console.log('SENDING LambdaClient. command: ', command);      
      const resp  = await lambdaClient.invoke(command);
      console.log('Returned from LAmbda call. resp: ', resp.Payload);
      //const result = Buffer.from(resp.Payload).toString();
      const result = (new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(resp.Payload));
      console.log('Converted result from buffer: ', result);            
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('There was an error invoking Lambda DB function: ', err);
        return false;
    }
   }
```

I also tried using this method (showing only skeleton here) instead:

```
import { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda"; 
...
const client = new LambdaClient(config);
const command = new InvokeCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
```

Same behavior, though.

This is the Lambda (NodeJS 18.x) code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { SignatureV4 } from '@aws-sdk/signature-v4';
import { Sha256 } from '@aws-crypto/sha256-js';

const {
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
  CALL_SIGNATURE
} = process.env;

const sigv4 = new SignatureV4({
  service: 'neptune-db',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    sessionToken: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
  },
  sha256: Sha256,
});


const validateSignature = async (requestSignature) => {
  //Lambda call permission validator
  if (requestSignature!=CALL_SIGNATURE) {
    throw new Error('Function call signature does not match');
  }
};


const decodeQuery = async (queryText) => {
    //Decodes some chars in the raw query text for Lambda to process properly
    let result = queryText.replace(/%7B/g, "{");
    result = result.replace(/%7D/g, "}");
    return result;
  };


export const handler = async (event) => {
  
  // retrieve signature and payload
  const requestSignature = event.headers.SignatureHeader;
  //const requestSignature = event.body.SignatureHeader;
  console.log('event received: ', event);
  
  try {
        await validateSignature(requestSignature); // throws if invalid signature
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: `Function permission error: ${error}`,
        };
    }
  
  const requestPayload = event.body; //Passed openCypher query string
  console.log('requestPayload: ', requestPayload);
  const signatureQuery = await decodeQuery(requestPayload);
  
  const ocQuery = requestPayload;
  const API_URL = "https://****.****.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/openCypher?query=" + ocQuery;
  const apiUrl = new URL(API_URL);

  const signed = await sigv4.sign({
    method: 'GET',
    hostname: apiUrl.host,
    path: apiUrl.pathname,
    protocol: apiUrl.protocol,
    query: {
      query: signatureQuery
      },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      host: apiUrl.hostname, 
    }
  });

  try {
    const result = await axios({
      ...signed,
      url: API_URL,
    });

    console.log('Successfully received result: ', JSON.stringify(result.data));
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: result.data
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('An error occurred', error);

    throw error;
  }
};
```

Please, what am I missing?
Thank you!

Comment: Don't set the invocation type to Event. That is an async invocation which results in the client not receiving the actual response from the lambda invocation but just the response that the lambda "accepted" the invocation.

Comment: Oh my! thank you! why don't you write this as an answer so I can credit you on this?